# GCP Engine Ubuntu 16.04 crashed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04, google-compute-engine

A VM on GCP running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS can't be reached through SSH anymore after restarting. Getting the following error in serial console:

```
stateengine.go:98: state ensure error: Get 
https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
```

How can this be addressed?

Comment: This is related to snapd, you can check the status [here](http://status.snapcraft.io/) for the  **api.snapcraft.io**. they were some ntermittent access issue in few services on 18 July, but today it seems good.

Comment: some Ubuntu images 16.04 has some kernel issues and crash on booting, there is a workaround is to use the ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20170125 images or set the interface to "NVME", you can follow this topic [Here](https://issuetracker.google.com/111753610)